# Existence of Polynomial with whom product contains only prime powers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}$ be a polynomial of degree $n>0$. Let $p_1,p_2,p_3..p_{n+1}$ be distinct prime numbers. Show that there exists a non-zero polynomial $g \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $fg=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}c_iX^{p_i} $ with $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

If I want to find a polynomial then it must be of degree $p_{n+1}-n$.
So I assumed a polynomial $g=\sum_{i=1}^{p_{n+1}-n}b_iX^{i}$.

Multiplying $f$ & $g$ and equating the non-prime power coefficents to $0$ where our variables are $b_i's$ (they are $p_{n+1}-n+1$ in number) and we have $p_{n+1}-n+1$ equations.
One solution is all $b_i=0$ and in this case it is zero polynomial.

How do I proceed further? Is there another way to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\Phi: \mathbb{Q}_{p_{n+1}-n}[X] \to \mathbb{Q}_{p_{n+1}}[X]$ defined by letting $\Phi(g) = fg$.

Now let $V = Vect (X^{p_1},...,X^{p_{n+1}})$ (I'm assuming $p_1<...<p_{n+1}$ hence $V$ is a subvector space of $\mathbb{Q}_{p_{n+1}}[X]$)

As the $p_i$ are distinct, $\mathrm{dim}V = n+1$.

Moreover, $f$ is nonzero so $\Phi$ is injective, so its image has dimension $p_{n+1}-n+1$.

Now assume the conclusion is not met, this means $\mathrm{Im}\Phi \cap V = \{0\}$. This in turn implies that $V$ is included in a subspace $S$ such that $\mathrm{Im}\Phi \oplus S = \mathbb{Q}_{p_{n+1}}[X]$. This implies $n+1= \mathrm{dim}V\leq \mathrm{dim}\mathbb{Q}_{p_{n+1}}[X] - \mathrm{dim}\mathrm{Im}\Phi = p_{n+1}+1 - (p_{n+1} -n +1) = n$, a contradiction.

Hence $\mathrm{Im}\Phi \cap V \neq \{0\}$, so there is $g$ such that $fg= \Phi(g) \neq 0$ (in particular $g\neq 0$) and $fg \in V$, so $fg = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}c_i X^{p_i}$ for some $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$

Note that this has nothing to do with prime numbers.

Comment: How did you get an idea to approach this?

Comment: I didn't really see the point of the $p_i$ being prime because when you multiply polynomials, it amounts to adding the degrees in some sense, and primes aren't that well related to addition. So I thought this should work simply because there are many exponents, and this made me think of some dimensional argument, where linear algebra is most helpful. Then it turns out that the dimensions worked out: there had to be an intersection

Comment: please explain me what you did after "Now assume that the conclusion is not meet......."

Comment: Well I simply restated your problem in a linear-algebraic way, that is : "there is $g$ such that $fg$ is in the desired space" is the same as "some element of the image is nonzero and in the desired space"; then I simply included some dimensionality argument to show that this must be the case

Comment: please explain me what you did after "Now assume that the conclusion is not meet......." I couldn't understand from this in turn implies that V Is included in a subspace S.......

Comment: Essentially I'm just saying that if the sum $V+ \mathrm{Im}\Phi$ is direct, then $\mathrm{dim}V+ \dim\mathrm{Im}\Phi \leq p_{n+1}+1$; but I know $\mathrm{dim}V = n+1$, and I also know $\dim\mathrm{Im}\Phi = p_{n+1} - n +1$ which makes the whole situation impossible